# My laptop display feels really buggy and it lags

Tags: lenovo-laptop

So, I recently purchased a medium end Lenovo Flex 5, with the below mentioned configuration, and yet the display feels really lagging. Like, when I open a new program or a new tab in a browser, the first 15-20 seconds have a SIGNIFICANT lag between a mouse click/keyboard press and the response time. It kinda improves after those 20 seconds, but anytime I change to another program that is already open, it lags. Has someone faced similar situation or does someone have a solution to this?

The configuration is:
Intel i7-1065G7,
16 GB DDR4 RAM,
NVIDIA MX330 2 GB,
4K display.

I am inclined to think it could be due some bottleneck in communication between the CPU and the GPU, but I am not sure. Please help.

Comment: Does this happen when [booting in Safe mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/)?

Comment: @harrymc Sorry for the late reply..Yes, the problem persists in Safe Mode.

Comment: Things to try: (1) Check the SMART data of your system disk with a utility such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1624313/edit) a screenshot into your post. (2) Run `chkdsk` to check for errors, (3) See if you can find any useful messages in the Event Log.